# Is there a way to make flexdashboard respond to user input?

Tags: shiny, r-markdown, dashboard, analysis, flexdashboard

I am a new R user, currently developing a dashboard for my project. This dashboard displays the overall attendance summary for schools.  I added a side bar and I want users to be able to select factors i.e. 'region' in the sidebar to see the results. The result that is currently being displayed is the overall result. How do I connect the sidebar to the various sections of the dashboard to enable the results to vary based on user selection?

The code can be found here https://github.com/Abdulkarim1990/kadiri1990/blob/42ca201fe90beda11098778c6702a8a833b1e75c/PLC%20dashboard%202.Rmd

I tried googling and varying the code to no end. I need help.

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at [Using shiny with flexdashboard](https://rstudio.github.io/flexdashboard/articles/shiny.html) which also offers a lot of examples.

Comment: you may want to look into the r package [`crosstalk`](https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/using.html).